# How can i improve my recurrent neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I want to implement a recurrent neural network for natural language inference. I'm new in this topic and this is a task from a module from my university, so i've had some code beforehand which i tried to adopt for this task. The problem i have is that with my current implementation i get a accuracy of 0.5633 like everytime. So far i've implemented this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import Adam, SGD, Adagrad
from tqdm import tqdm
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string 

s_words = stopwords.words('english')
puncts = string.punctuation

word2index_combined = {}

def data_preprocessing(fname):
    sentence_pairs = []
    data = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t')
    sentences_1 = data['sentence1'].tolist()
    sentences_1 = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences_1]
    sentences_1 = [[w.lower() for w in sentences_1[i] if w.lower() not in s_words and w.lower() not in puncts] for i in range(len(sentences_1))] 
    sentences_2 = data['sentence2'].tolist()
    sentences_2 = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences_2]
    sentences_2 = [[w.lower() for w in sentences_2[i] if w.lower() not in s_words and w.lower() not in puncts] for i in range(len(sentences_2))] 
    labels = data['label'].astype(int).tolist()  
    k = 1
    for i in range(len(sentences_1)):
        for w in sentences_1[i]:
            if w not in word2index:
                word2index[w] = k
                k += 1
        for w in sentences_2[i]:
            if w not in word2index:
                word2index[w] = k
                k += 1       
    return sentences_1, sentences_2, labels

class data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sent_1, sent_2, labels, padding):
        self.padding = padding
        self.sent_1 = self._pad(sent_1)
        self.sent_2 = self._pad(sent_2)        
        self.labels = labels
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sent_1)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        s1 = [word2index.get(word, 0) for word in self.sent_1[idx]]
        s2 = [word2index.get(word, 0) for word in self.sent_2[idx]]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return torch.tensor(s1), torch.tensor(s2), torch.tensor(label)
    
    def _pad(self, sentences):
        sents = []
        for sent in sentences:
            if len(sent) < self.padding:
                sent += [0] * (self.padding - len(sent))
            else:
                sent = sent[:self.padding]
            sents.append(sent)
        return sents
        

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hidden_size, emb_dim, num_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size+1
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        
        self.emb = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.emb_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.lstm = nn.GRU(self.emb_dim, self.hidden_size, num_layers=self.num_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*2, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)
        
    def forward(self, inp_seq1, inp_seq2):
        batch_size = inp_seq1.size(0)
        inp1 = self.emb(inp_seq1)
        inp2 = self.emb(inp_seq2)
        h_0 = (torch.rand(self.num_layers*2, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        packed_output1, last_hidden1 = self.lstm(inp1, h_0)
        packed_output2, last_hidden2 = self.lstm(inp2, h_0)
        out = torch.cat((last_hidden1[-1], last_hidden2[-1]), dim=1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

def validate(model, dev_loader):
    label_pred = []
    label_original = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X1, X2, y in dev_loader:
            out = model(X1, X2)
            label = torch.argmax(out, dim=1)
            label_pred.extend(label.numpy().tolist())
            label_original.extend(y.numpy().tolist())
    
    return accuracy_score(label_original, label_pred)   

def train(model, train_loader, dev_loader):
    val_accuracy = 0
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    epochs = 10
    for e in range(epochs):
        for X1, X2, y in tqdm(train_loader):
            if X1.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:  # Check if batch sizes match
                continue
            out = model(X1, X2)
            loss = criterion(out, y)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        
        model.eval()
        acc = validate(model, dev_loader)
        print(f"accuracy at the end of epoch - {e}: {acc}")
        if acc > val_accuracy:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'rnn_model.pt')
            val_accuracy = acc
        model.train()     

train_sentences, train_labels = data_preprocessing('WNLI/train.tsv')
test_sentences, test_labels = data_preprocessing('WNLI/test.tsv')
dev_sentences, dev_labels = data_preprocessing('WNLI/dev.tsv')

train_data = data(train_sentences, train_labels)
test_data = data(test_sentences, test_labels)
dev_data = data(dev_sentences, dev_labels)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, collate_fn=train_data.collate_fn, drop_last=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32, collate_fn=test_data.collate_fn, drop_last=True)
dev_loader = DataLoader(dev_data, batch_size=32, collate_fn=dev_data.collate_fn, drop_last=True)

vocab_size = len(word2index_combined)
hidden_size = 1024
emb_dim = 250
num_layers = 3
model = RNN(vocab_size, hidden_size, emb_dim, num_layers)
train(model, train_loader, dev_loader)
```

So far i've tried it with different batch sizes, number of layers, number of epochs, hidden sizes, embedding dimensions and learning rate but i still get the same accuracy or worse. So i don't really know where the problem could be and at this point i think maybe i'm going into the wrong direction with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, one thing that is currently very hot in natural language processing is using self-attention. I recommend using [MultiHeadAttention](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) as the first layer after input. Study it a bit to get the parameters right for your problem but it might give you the edge you seek.

This [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.02181#:%7E:text=The%20attention%20mechanism%20is%20a,to%20its%20higher%20level%20representation.) might help you to understand how it works for your problem.

Also using the weighted cross-entropy loss function might help you considering how text usually favors the use of certain words with a greater frequency than others.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the task specifically says to use a recurrent neural network. If im right, with multiheadattention it would be no longer a recurrent neural network

Comment: You can use a combination of both, the attention layer will give weight to what it considers to be more important data, this you can feed as input to you RNN or LSTM model